# CSS file not loading on HTML

Tags: html, css, file

I am currently coding in notepad, not sure if that contributes to my issue or not. But I have changed the link to the css file multiple times and it is still not showing up on my web page. This is my code:

```
<DOCTYPE!>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "UTF-8'>
<meta name="description" content="resume">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript">
<meta name="author" content="Tayler Pierre">
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Caviar-Dreams rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>
```

I can not figure this out please help.

Comment: close quote is missing in href in lint tag. so change to `<link href="https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Caviar-Dreams' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three errors in your code:

1. `<meta charset= "UTF-8'>`
2. `<link href="https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Caviar-Dreams rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>`
3. `<DOCTYPE!>`

Just for safety, also change:

4. `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Overall this is what your code should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="resume">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript">
<meta name="author" content="Tayler Pierre">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Caviar-Dreams" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>
```

Comment: Why down vote? Have I done something wrong? I am pretty sure I covered all the errors but am fairly new here so could you let me know.

Comment: Probably because someone felt the answer didn't add to the answers already given and your formatting is a bit strange, I'll suggest and edit.

Comment: Ok no worries thanks for letting me know @KevinVoorn

Comment: I didn't downvote though :) I suggested an edit which changed every single improvement to a code block with all improvements in place. This makes the answer more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks mate took on board your edits and simplified my original answer, also accepted your edit to improve your rep too :)

Comment: I made the changes to my code I even took out the front squirrel just to see if that was the issue but my css is still not loading with my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to include 2 different CSS files, it is unclear which one is not loading for you. In case your own `style.css` is not loading, you are probably trying to include it from a different path then where to actual file is.

For the `https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Caviar-Dreams` font file, you are missing `"` in the include it self. Replace the line with the following:

```
<link href="https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Caviar-Dreams" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

You have some other minor errors in your code, [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53440824/4274852) of [Ben Tegoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9763334/ben-tegoni) for some suggested improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to properly close the href attribute of the last link tag.

```
<link href="https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Caviar-Dreams" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'/>
```